# Reusable forms in Django app

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

**Short:**

I'd like to create an app which provides a well formatted form that can be imported into other apps. Doing this using nothing but `ModelForm` results in partial success as it renders only the form fields without any of the additionally required elements like buttons. This however should also be encapsulated in the app.

**Long:**

For a better understanding lets assume we have an app called `blog` and one called `comments`. They've been separated since comments may also be used in other places and apps. `comments` should provide a form which is then added to the view or the template of `blog`

So here's some **pseudo code** for better a understanding.

comments/models.py:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    comment = models.TextField()
    author = models.CharField(max_length=64)
```

comments/forms.py:

```
class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm)
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
```

comments/templates/comments/comment_form.html:

```
<form method="post" action="#">
    {{ formfields }}
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Clearly there's a step missing since the `ModelForm` and the template are not brought together. My goal now is to import exacly such a marriage to `blog`

blog/views.py

```
def render_article(request):
    context = {
        ...
        comment_form: <SOMETHING THAT CREATES A NICE TEMPLATE BASED HTML FORM>
    }

    return render(request, 'blog/article.html', context)
```

In essence I'm looking for a single object of function that I can use in any kind of app to provide a complete form. That way it always looks the same in all apps.

How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could override `django.forms.Form.__unicode__` in your form:

```
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

class MyForm(forms.Form):
   ...
   def __unicode__(self):
       html = super(MyForm, self).__unicode__
       html = html + '<button type="submit">Submit</button>'
       // or whatever — render a wrapper template, anything
       return mark_safe(html)
```